# access JdbcTemplate in constructor of SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application and would like to access the provided JdbcTemplate in the constructor.  I'm trying to cache some data from the database upon class instantiation.  My Groovy code looks like this:

```
@Repository
class EarthquakeRepository {

@Autowired
private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

public EarthquakeRespository() {
    //fails because jdbcTemplate is null
    assert jdbcTemplate
}
...
```

Even though the constructor is getting fired, the jdbcTemplate is null. Other methods in the repository do have access to the jdbcTemplate.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

--john

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use field injection, as you have here, an instance of the class is created, and therefore the constructor is called, before the injection occurs. That's why jdbcTemplate is null when you try to use it in the constructor. It has to happen this way around as, without calling the constructor first, there's nothing for the dependency to be injected into.

You could change your repostory to use constructor injection: declare JdbcTemplate as a parameter of the constructor and annotate the constructor with `@Autowired`. You can then use the JdbcTemplate in the constructor if you want to.

You could also add a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` to your repository class. This method will be called after the instance has been created (so constructor injection's occurred) and also after field injection's been performed if you continue with that approach. You'd then use JdbcTemplate in this method to perform the caching.

My recommendation would be to move to using constructor injection as it makes your classes easier to test (it's easy to pass a mock into a constructor) and to move your use of JdbcTemplate into a `@PostConstruct`-annotated method, thereby keeping the constructor as lightweight as possible.